# need help electronic/relay problem phone horn

Tags: relay

I need to ring a phone that activates a loud ass horn. Phone has no audio ports. I'd be tapping into the 2 wires that connect from phone circuit board to the phone ring speaker.

Inside the handset, the 2 wires show .035-.045 VAC (probed with multimeter while the phone "rings") and connect to an 8 Ohm 2W speaker inside the phone. This 8 Ohm 2W speaker needs to be replaced with a very loud horn or buzzer.

-I purchased a generic 12VDC piezo horn. Need to feed it 12VDC when phone rings. That's all.

I'm stumped. Low signal relay? Some type of inline amp? I can solder a bit, and have only  a very basic understanding of this stuff.

Do I look for a low signal relay? like .03VAC to 12VDC?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I recommend making a circuit with a few op amps involved to make a filter.  First stage is to buffer and frequency limit the signal so you can get a simple on-off. Last stage should likely be a comparator and buffer.  You can then feed that through a mosfet or relay with appropriate voltage and current capabilities (there are pretty beefy 12V mosfets out there!).  What are the horn's specs? I'm going off a doorbell chime and patching into the button for these suggestions for now.